# Ubuntu 16.04 - Not reporting memory use properly?

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I thought I had a handle on memory in Linux, but this issue is making me doubt myself.

I have a server running Proxmox 5.4-13, on which I have a container running Ubuntu 16.04. This container runs various processes including Apache, PHP-FPM, Memcached, Redis and also Puppeteer with headless Chrome. The container has been allocated roughly 100Gb of RAM.

It seems that since we've started using Puppeteer/headless chrome more, we are seeing some sort of memory leak - or at least memory being used up and then not freed by the kernel? This could just be a coincidence. The memory in use by the server slowly grows and grows. I cannot determine what is using memory. Stopping or killing services does not account for the used memory. Rebooting the container returns everything to normal, before it slowly grows again, over the space of several weeks.

At the time of writing, almost 30Gb of memory is in use (1 week since last reboot).

```
$ free -m
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache    available
Mem:         102400       28128       63454        2562       10817       74271
```

If I run ps_mem (https://github.com/pixelb/ps_mem) then this returns a total of 5.2Gb used across my processes. Running top/htop does not show me what is using the memory.

```
 Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used       Program

292.0 KiB +  66.5 KiB = 358.5 KiB       autossh (3)
468.0 KiB + 104.5 KiB = 572.5 KiB       su
432.0 KiB + 160.5 KiB = 592.5 KiB       agetty (3)
528.0 KiB + 222.0 KiB = 750.0 KiB       sh (6)
516.0 KiB + 354.5 KiB = 870.5 KiB       master
484.0 KiB + 390.5 KiB = 874.5 KiB       pickup
856.0 KiB +  46.5 KiB = 902.5 KiB       systemd-logind
572.0 KiB + 360.5 KiB = 932.5 KiB       qmgr
852.0 KiB + 267.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB       dbus-daemon
816.0 KiB + 308.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB       cron (3)
  1.3 MiB +  95.5 KiB =   1.4 MiB       ntpd
940.0 KiB + 619.0 KiB =   1.5 MiB       sudo (2)
  1.4 MiB + 164.5 KiB =   1.5 MiB       pgbouncer
  1.8 MiB + 168.5 KiB =   2.0 MiB       atop
  1.0 MiB +   1.0 MiB =   2.1 MiB       polkitd
  2.1 MiB +  25.5 KiB =   2.1 MiB       rsyslogd
  1.2 MiB +   1.0 MiB =   2.2 MiB       accounts-daemon
  2.1 MiB + 426.5 KiB =   2.6 MiB       smtpd
  2.1 MiB + 635.0 KiB =   2.7 MiB       (sd-pam) (2)
  2.7 MiB + 317.0 KiB =   3.0 MiB       sftp-server (14)
  1.7 MiB +   1.3 MiB =   3.0 MiB       zabbix_agentd (6)
  2.1 MiB +   2.1 MiB =   4.2 MiB       systemd (3)
  6.0 MiB + 880.5 KiB =   6.8 MiB       ssh (3)
  7.1 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   8.2 MiB       bash (4)
  3.9 MiB +   7.5 MiB =  11.5 MiB       sshd (15)
 13.0 MiB + 846.5 KiB =  13.8 MiB       unattended-upgr
 13.4 MiB +   1.1 MiB =  14.5 MiB       supervisord
 62.4 MiB +  20.5 KiB =  62.4 MiB       redis-server
 22.9 MiB +  57.0 MiB =  79.9 MiB       systemd-journald
 77.2 MiB +  24.4 MiB = 101.5 MiB       apache2 (5)
102.5 MiB +   9.2 MiB = 111.6 MiB       php7.3 (5)
111.6 MiB +  34.3 MiB = 145.9 MiB       phantomjs (4)
521.2 MiB + 148.5 KiB = 521.4 MiB       memcached
  4.1 GiB +  69.9 MiB =   4.2 GiB       php-fpm7.3 (20)
---------------------------------
                          5.2 GiB
=================================
```

How can I determine what is using the memory?

Edit 1:

```
$ mount | grep tmpfs
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=492k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/33 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13191772k,mode=700,uid=33,gid=33)
tmpfs on /run/user/2001 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13191772k,mode=700,uid=2001,gid=2001)
```

Comment: Do you have a process writing to a location mounted as tmpfs (in-ram filesystem). It's common for /tmp to tmpfs by default. Also, your application RAM usage is around 18GB, not close to 30.

Comment: I've added tmpfs mounts to my original post. I haven't set any up myself, and don't believe I'm writing to any. When running 'free', it shows used as '28128', which is about 28Gb? Where did you see 18Gb?

Comment: 28128 - 10817 = 17311: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: OK - What is using the 18Gb then? In the two days since I posted, ps_mem now returns a total of 6.2Gb used. 'used' shows as 34529 and buff/cache as 14040, so the total used is now 20489. It's slowly getting worse. I can wait a couple more weeks and it'll be using more still...